# Input value Set using jquery's selector does not post

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-views, django-templates

There's this issue where I created a form using django. The form contains two charfields for name and address, and two datetimefields one for a start_date and the other for a stop_date. Finally there are two radio buttons, such that:

- when the first is checked, the start_date field's value is set to date.now() using jquery's selector
- when the second radio button is checked, the start_date and stop_date fields are disabled, still using jquery's selector.
  The above code works well. However, when the start_date's value is successfully set, I have to post the form data using jquery ajax post method to a django view, the start_date's value is not posted at all, while the other field values are. I don't know how to go about this issue.

Here's my code:

**template.html:**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<div class="center">
 <form action="" invalidate>
 {% crispy form form.helper %}
</form>
</div>
```

**script.js:**

```js
$('input:radio').click(function){
  if ($(this).val() === '1'){
    var start_date = new Date();
    $('#id_start_date').val(start_date);
  }
  else if ($(this).val() === '0'){  document.getElementById('id_stop_date').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('id_start_date').disabled = true;
  }
    
}

$("form").on("submit", function (e){
  var name = $("#id_name");
  var type = $("id_type");
  var start_date = $("id_start_date");
  var stop_date = $("id_stop_date");

 $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"{% url 'postAccount' %}",
    data:{
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').Val(),
      name:name, type:type, start_date:start_date, stop_date: stop_date
    },
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response){
      var response = JSON.parse(response ['instance']),
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
e.preventDefault();
});
```

**views.py:**

```py
def postAccount(request):
 if is_ajax(request) and request.method == 'POST':
  form = AccountForm (request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
   instance = form.save()
   ser_instance = serializers.serialize('json', [ser_instance,])
   return JsonResponse({"instance":ser_instance}, status=200)
 return JsonResponse ({"error":""}, status=400)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled inputs won't appear in `request.POST` - you might have better luck using the `readOnly` attribute instead, it will do basically the same thing but will still include the value in `request.POST`

Comment: Yes I did just that earlier and it solved the problem